# Angular 2+ : Router changes Route / router-outlet does not recognize it and displays old component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I currently have a problem with the Angular Router. To be more specific with the router-outlet.

**My Problem:**
In my Use-Case I have a Container-Component which contains 1+N instances of the same Component (FeatureCardComponent).
The FeauterCardComponent contains the router-outlet. This Component has two states ( Active or Inactive ). In the Active State the router-outlet is rendered within the Component. Only one FeatureCardComponent is active at the same time. So only one router-outlet is in the DOM. If a FeatureCardComponent is set to active it should be routing to a specfic Component ( in my example a Featureone or Featuretwo ).

**Behaviour:**
If I change the States the first time, everything works as intended. But if I change the States again, the same Component is shown in the router-outlet as in the first change. The URL shows also the correct route. In simpler terms: If I toggle once -> I see B. If I toggle again -> I also see B, but should see A.

It seems to be a racecondition, because if i use `setTimeout(() => {}, 0);` it works correctly as mentioned in this thread: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful).

I have here a small stackblitz project which shows my Problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjcapf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard-container%2Fcard-container.component.ts

I have tried several approaches but none of them work. I would like to avoid the setTimeout Function.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: When I check your code, I can see the toggle fine without timeout. Even I can see the same thing in the URL on every subsequent click. I am seeing the toggle b/w featureone and featuretwo. Can you be little more specific?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Sure. if you toggle with the Button "without Timeout" you see that the Featuretwo is loaded correctly in the router-outlet. if you toggle again with the Button "without Timeout" it should load the Featureone in the router-outlet, but it shows Featuretwo again. If you do this with the "with Timeout" Button, it displays correctly Featureone on the second toggle. Does this help you ?

Comment: Actually, I can't replicate same issue on stackblitz.

Comment: Maybe the naming is a little bit confusing. i adjusted the naming now. In the black container is the the router-outlet which should always displaying the active feature ( Featureone or Featuretwo ). If you toggle now with the "without Timeout" Button, you should see that in the black container the Featuretwo is displayed instead of the Featureone.